# Spring Transactional: how to propagate existing transaction and update not-commited enity via native query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have service logic, which interacts with spring JPA:

```
@Transactional
fun someLogic() {
   val myEntity = Enity()
   myRepo.save(myEntity)
   ...
   someInnerLogic() // !
}

@Transactional
fun someInnerLogic() {
   myRepo.performNativeQuery()
}
```

And JPA interface (JpaRepository) from spring data:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(
        nativeQuery = true,
        value = """
                   UPDATE my_entity SET ...
               """
)

fun performNativeQuery()
```

Actually, when `someInnerLogic` executed, there is no any updates of existing (non-commited) entity. How can I propagate transaction in that case?

Comment: all your changes are running in same transaction. That's the reason

Comment: @Lucia and how can I handle it in right way?

Comment: remove transactional on below method
fun someLogic() {
}

Comment: @Lucia Mb better to change propagation level? I'm not sure, that's removal of transactional is a good idea.

Comment: what exactly is your requirement here?
you have two things going on there saving entity and then updating  it in some native query. So you want both them to be atomic? both of them should either succeed or fail?

Comment: @Lucia So, first method (someLogic) is very important. Because we persist entity and save data consistency from duplicated entities, it's like a shield in my logic. Then I need to perform second method (someInnerLogic) with some fallback scenario. Also, there is not only native query, other network calls too. And if it fails somehow - I need to start fallback logic. But anyway, I need to perform native query in consistent way. And yep, looks like in that case I have protection in case of first method invocation, it's save me from inconsistency. Am I right?

Comment: you are not getting my question.  you want both the things to run in same transaction? or not is my question. From your expectation it looks like you want saveEntity and someInnerLogic()  to run in different transaction.
If you have both these methods someLogic and someInnerLogic in the same class then both will run in the same transaction.(due to spring proxy mechanism)
If you want those two methods to run in different transactions, then you have to separate them into separate classes

Comment: For more info you can see
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation